# Getting "No Module Named Spotipy"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, module, pycharm

When I try to run the line:

```
import spotipy
```

I get the error that there is `no module named spotipy`. I have tried using `pip`, `pip3`, and `easy install` to install the module. When I run pip freeze I can see that spotipy is installed as version `2.4.4`.

What could possibly be going wrong?

I am using PyCharm if that matters.

Comment: @Procyclinsur pip freeze is a command to show all the installed packages by pip. I was just saying that it correctly showed the installed version as 2.4.4

Comment: Yes, I realized that now, I deleted my comment because it wasn't helpful.. Ill keep searching for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From pycharm,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of  Available packages. Then search for `spotipy` python package.

Then click on `Install package` to install the package.

Comment: @john: This works well in my PC. Please let me know after trying this ?

Comment: This is what finally worked, thank you. Had no idea you could manually install modules on an interpreter this way.

Answer (score 0):

At PyCharm:

File -> settings -> Project Interpreter, then choose or create a `Virtualenv Environment`

Comment: When I do this it lets me type the import line and also import SpotifyClientCredentials but when I run code I now get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotipy'" in the console.

Comment: @John It sounds strange, maybe you need to learn how to use pycharm with virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the IDE that you're using isn't instantiated inside of the virtual environment. Try closing it, and first activating your venv through the activate script then opening it again with `code .` or whatever other IDE you have on path.